# Source code navigation and JavaDoc bug in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-indigo

I have a problem with **Eclipse Indigo** regarding library source code. When I open a library class (e.g. from the JDK, but also from some other included libraries, such as Guava), either using the `Open Type` dialogue or simply through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+ click` on the class name or some of its methods, once in a while (not always) something breaks.

Don't get me wrong, the source is always displayed without any problem (either JDK source shipped with the JDK itself or Guava source downloaded by Maven). What actually stops to work:

- When I open the **Quick Outline** popup in that given class using `Ctrl + O`, the list of methods and fields displays normally, but when I click on any of them, Eclipse doesn't move the view on it as it should. Also Ctrl + clicking any of the methods or fields of that class in my code doesn't bring me directly to it, but simply at the top of the source file.
- When I hover over that said class or its methods, no JavaDoc appears in the popup as you can see in the attached image. I am in the `HashSet` class, the source is clearly there, but it isn't displayed in the popup.

[image: HashSet JavaDoc gone]

I found out that this can be fixed by opening the **Outline View** and briefly clicking through the class's methods and fields. After a few clicks, Eclipse catches on and starts to work correctly, but only for this one class, not for all which are broken in this way at the moment.

Has anybody met this kind of bug? Is it tracked at Eclipse Bugzilla? Thanks in advance for any advice.

For completeness, this is my configuration:

```
Windows 7 Professional x64
Oracle JDK 1.7 Update 2 32b
Eclipse Indigo for Java EE Developers 32b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I didn't find out how to solve the problem in Indigo, but updating to Juno fixed it.

Comment: I have Eclipse Kepler – the same problem. It looks like Outline navigation is pain for Eclipse. I have only one JDK installed, and sources are proper. Navigation in `HashSet` works fine, but does not work in `String`.

Answer (score 1):

your issue #2 may be resolved by following these steps :

1. Go to http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/download.jsp and choose to
   download the JDK 5.0 Source Code.
2. For JDK 5.0, select Download(SCSL source).
3. Download JDK (SCSL) 5.0 (1.5.0). This will give you a file jdk-1_5_0-src.scsl.zip. You do not need to unzip this file; Eclipse likes it the way it is.
4. In Eclipse, go to Projects -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and expand JRE System Library [jre 1.5.0], then rt.jar. Select Source attachment and click Edit...
5. Select the above zip file. and Finish by exiting the dialog boxes.

[source](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/Pages/eclipse-faq.html#run_javadoc)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you, but this unfortunately doesn't really help. The problem isn't that there isn't any source attached to JRE (there actually is src.zip attached to rt.jar, otherwise I wouldn't be able to make the screenshot), but the fact that Eclipse fails to display it in popup box for some classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like wrong sources are attached to the libs inside Eclipse.

I had similar symptoms in a project where a class exist in both: inside a lib and in the project's src folder. Same canonical class name, but different implementations.

I would recommend to verify (or reinstall) your JDK-Installation and re-configurating it in Eclipse.

Hitting `Ctrl+Shift+T` and typing `HashSet` and taking a screenshot of that window may help here, too.